# What decimal values are represented by the following bit pattern?

Tags: floating-point, binary, bit

0 010 1101

Sign is 0 which is positive, the exponent is 010 which becomes -1

I don't understand what to do with the four significand digits. According to the textbook, the answer is .90625 but when I add the places up I get

```
1 = .5
1 = .25
0 = 0
1 = .175
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Can I assume that it isn't possible to get .90625 with just a four bit significand?

Answer (score 2):

There is a leading 1 that is not stored. Also, the least significant bit's value is .0625, not .175. I add 1+.5+.25+0+.0625, getting 1.8125. Divide that by 2 for the -1 exponent, and the result is 0.90625.

Comment: Heck, I wanted to post exactly the same, but got called away. ;-)